# Фильтрация по айди при наличии общих полей id в третьей модели для двух других моделей Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, фильтрация

Пишу учебное приложение на флаттер для рыбалки и встал вопрос о том, как правильно отфильтровать данные из трех моделей, если третья модель имеет в себе значения айди из предыдущих двух.
В документации написано, что нужно использовать метод `where`, тут увидел похожие вопросы, но в них фильтрация идет лишь по общему айди из двух моделей. В моем же случае их три и две из них не связаны ни по айди, ни по значениям типа `String`. Каким образом их можно связать между собой и получить уже отфильтрованные параметры?

Вот эти три класса:

```
//класс модели для снастей
class FishingTackle {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  FishingTackle({this.id, this.name});
}

//класс моделей для наживки
class FishBait {
  final int TypeId;
  final String BaitName;

  FishBait({this.TypeId, this.BaitName});
}

//класс моделей для времени приобритения
class TimeByuing {
  final int id;
  final int TypeId;
  final DateTime time;

  TimeByuing({this.id, this.TypeId, this.time});
}
```

Как видно, класс `TimeByuing` имеет общие айди с двумя предыдущими, но я никак не могу понять, как их связать между собой и поместить в `UI` отфильтрованное. Может их нужно как-то по отдельности отфильтровать, а потом уже результат этих фильтраций снова пропустить через `where`?

```
class Fishing extends StatelessWidget {
  List<FishingTackle> tackle = <FishingTackle>[
    FishingTackle(id: 1, name: 'Вентерь'),
    FishingTackle(id: 2, name: 'Гарпун'),
    FishingTackle(id: 2, name: 'Грузило'),
    FishingTackle(id: 1, name: 'Жерлица'),
    FishingTackle(id: 1, name: 'Закидушка'),
  ];

  List<FishBait> bait = <FishBait>[
    FishBait(TypeId: 1, BaitName: 'Мотыль'),
    FishBait(TypeId: 2, BaitName: 'Опарыш'),
    FishBait(TypeId: 2, BaitName: 'Короед'),
    FishBait(TypeId: 1, BaitName: 'Казара'),
    FishBait(TypeId: 1, BaitName: 'Стрекоза'),
  ];

  List<TimeByuing> buying = <TimeByuing>[
    TimeByuing(
        id: 1, TypeId: 1, time: DateTime.parse('2021-01-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 2, TypeId: 2, time: DateTime.parse('2021-03-21 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 2, TypeId: 2, time: DateTime.parse('2021-05-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 1, TypeId: 1, time: DateTime.parse('2020-12-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 1, TypeId: 1, time: DateTime.parse('2021-02-18 00:00:00.000')),
  ];


  List<TimeByuing> get buyingProperties {
    return buying.where((element) => (element.id == element.id) && (element.TypeId == element.TypeId)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: buyingProperties.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(tackle[index].name),
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: buyingProperties.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(bait[index].BaitName),
                        trailing: Text(buying[index].time.toString()),
                      );
                    })
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

В, JS например, можно сделать нечто подобное, для фильтрации двух списков по айди:

```
let res = [];
   res = arr1.filter(el => {
      return !arr2.find(element => {
         return element.id === el.id;
      });
   });
   return res;
```

Можно ли нечто подобное сделать на Dart? Я попробовал вот такой код:

Взять за основу пустой массив куда будет складывать элементы и пустить их по циклу `forEach()`

```
List <AllFishes> result =  tackle.forEach((el) {
    return !bait.where((element) => element.TypeId == el.id);
    return result;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не оптимальный способ. Создаём список Common из трёх списков, естественно нужно добавить все возможные проверки.

```
void main() {
  List<FishingTackle> tackle = <FishingTackle>[
    FishingTackle(id: 1, name: 'Вентерь'),
    FishingTackle(id: 2, name: 'Гарпун'),
    FishingTackle(id: 3, name: 'Грузило'),
    FishingTackle(id: 4, name: 'Жерлица'),
    FishingTackle(id: 5, name: 'Закидушка'),
  ];

  List<FishBait> bait = <FishBait>[
    FishBait(typeId: 1, baitName: 'Мотыль'),
    FishBait(typeId: 2, baitName: 'Опарыш'),
    FishBait(typeId: 3, baitName: 'Короед'),
    FishBait(typeId: 4, baitName: 'Казара'),
    FishBait(typeId: 5, baitName: 'Стрекоза'),
  ];

  List<TimeByuing> buying = <TimeByuing>[
    TimeByuing(
        id: 5, typeId: 1, time: DateTime.parse('2021-01-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 4, typeId: 2, time: DateTime.parse('2021-03-21 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 3, typeId: 3, time: DateTime.parse('2021-05-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 2, typeId: 4, time: DateTime.parse('2020-12-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 1, typeId: 5, time: DateTime.parse('2021-02-18 00:00:00.000')),
  ];

  List<Common> common = merge(buying, bait, tackle).toList();

  print(common);
}

Iterable<Common> merge(List<TimeByuing> buying, List<FishBait> bait,
    List<FishingTackle> tackle) sync* {
  for (int i = 0; i < buying.length; i++) {
    var name = tackle.firstWhere((v) => v.id == buying[i].id).name;
    var baitName =
        bait.firstWhere((v) => v.typeId == buying[i].typeId).baitName;
    yield Common(
      id: buying[i].id,
      typeId: buying[i].typeId,
      name: name,
      baitName: baitName,
      time: buying[i].time,
    );
  }
}

class FishingTackle {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  FishingTackle({this.id, this.name});
}

class FishBait {
  final int typeId;
  final String baitName;

  FishBait({this.typeId, this.baitName});
}

class TimeByuing {
  final int id;
  final int typeId;
  final DateTime time;

  TimeByuing({this.id, this.typeId, this.time});
}

class Common {
  final int id;
  final int typeId;
  final String name;
  final String baitName;
  final DateTime time;

  Common({this.id, this.typeId, this.name, this.baitName, this.time});
  
  String toString() => 'Common(id: $id, typeId: $typeId, name: $name, baitName: $baitName, time: $time)';
}
```

---

Кода нужен список списков:

```
void main() {
  List<FishingTackle> tackle = <FishingTackle>[
    FishingTackle(id: 1, name: 'Вентерь'),
    FishingTackle(id: 2, name: 'Гарпун'),
    FishingTackle(id: 2, name: 'Грузило'),
    FishingTackle(id: 1, name: 'Жерлица'),
    FishingTackle(id: 1, name: 'Закидушка'),
  ];

  List<FishBait> bait = <FishBait>[
    FishBait(typeId: 1, baitName: 'Мотыль'),
    FishBait(typeId: 2, baitName: 'Опарыш'),
    FishBait(typeId: 2, baitName: 'Короед'),
    FishBait(typeId: 1, baitName: 'Казара'),
    FishBait(typeId: 1, baitName: 'Стрекоза'),
  ];

  List<TimeByuing> buying = <TimeByuing>[
    TimeByuing(
        id: 1, typeId: 1, time: DateTime.parse('2021-01-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 2, typeId: 2, time: DateTime.parse('2021-03-21 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 2, typeId: 2, time: DateTime.parse('2021-05-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 1, typeId: 1, time: DateTime.parse('2020-12-15 00:00:00.000')),
    TimeByuing(
        id: 1, typeId: 1, time: DateTime.parse('2021-02-18 00:00:00.000')),
  ];

  List<Common> common = merge(buying, bait, tackle).toList();

  print(common);
}

Iterable<Common> merge(List<TimeByuing> buying, List<FishBait> bait,
    List<FishingTackle> tackle) sync* {
  for (int i = 0; i < buying.length; i++) {
    var fishingTackle = tackle.where((v) => v.id == buying[i].id).toList();
    var fishBait = bait.where((v) => v.typeId == buying[i].typeId).toList();
    yield Common(
      id: buying[i].id,
      typeId: buying[i].typeId,
      fishingTackle: fishingTackle,
      fishBait: fishBait,
      time: buying[i].time,
    );
  }
}

class FishingTackle {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  
  String toString() => 'FishingTackle(id: $id, name: $name)';

  FishingTackle({this.id, this.name});
}

class FishBait {
  final int typeId;
  final String baitName;
  
  String toString() => 'FishBait(typeId: $typeId, baitName: $baitName)';

  FishBait({this.typeId, this.baitName});
}

class TimeByuing {
  final int id;
  final int typeId;
  final DateTime time;

  TimeByuing({this.id, this.typeId, this.time});
}

class Common {
  final int id;
  final int typeId;
  final List<FishingTackle> fishingTackle;
  final List<FishBait> fishBait;
  final DateTime time;

  Common({this.id, this.typeId, this.fishingTackle, this.fishBait, this.time});
  
  String toString() => 'Common(id: $id, typeId: $typeId, fishingTackle: $fishingTackle, fishBait: $fishBait, time: $time, id: $id)';
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, @MiT. Спасибо за помощь. Можно задать вам вопрос? Я сейчас поместил в UI этот код, но ListView.builder ругается и пишет, что RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 2: 2. Я делаю вот так: ```itemCount: common.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(common[index].fishingTackle[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text(common[index].fishBait[index].baitName), ```

Comment: Видел, что подобная проблема решалась тем, что в  просто добавляли в itemCount значения и все работало. Что я упускаю?

Comment: ```itemCount: common.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(common[index].fishingTackle.map((e) => e.name).toString()),
                  subtitle: Text(common[index].fishBait.map((e) => e.baitName).toString()),
                  trailing: Text(common[index].time.toString()),``` Немного додумался как вывести фильтрованные списки (чувствую себя нубярой, аж стыдно), но в юай выводятся сырые строки

Comment: @inkwelll075 так у вас список списков, вам нужно также для списков `FishingTackle` и `FishBait` проходить через цикл (`ListView.builder` например) или как у вас через map но, выдавать виджеты.